# How should i use/install docker CE on suse linux?

Tags: docker, suse

How should i use/install docker CE on suse linux.
As per docker , only docker Enterprise Edition is supported on suse linux.
Is there any alternative that i can still install Docker CE in Suse linux?

Answer (score 4):

It's available via openbuild in https://software.opensuse.org/package/docker

`sudo zypper install docker` should work too.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am using Suse EE not opensuse, would this work as well?

Comment: I can't test it but there are packages for SUSE SLE-12 and SUSE SLE-12-SP3. Also that's the command to install it as it's shown in the Docker guide for SUSE SLE-12 https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/singlehtml/book_sles_docker/book_sles_docker.html#cha.docker.installation